# Why don't I need to use chain rule to find the derivative of arccos (x^2)?

Tags: calculus

I thought that I would need to use chain rule because of x^2 but apparently this is not the case, according to the work-through on calcchat.com.

It shows the derivative as:
[-1 / sqrt(1-x^4)] * 2x

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you are doing shows you are in fact invoking the chain rule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *was* the chain rule! The $2x$ is the "derivative of the inside."

Comment: I see... thank you. One other question, where does the -1 come from? I thought it was -u' / sqrt(1-x^2)... wouldn't -u' in this case be -2x?

Comment: The minus is coming from the fact that the derivative of $\arccos(x)$ is $-1/\sqrt{1-x^2}$.

Comment: But since the inside function is x^2 in this case, shouldn't it be -2x?

Comment: You have $\arccos'(x^2)(2x)= -\dfrac{2x}{\sqrt{1-(x^2)^2}}$.